# Shell script truncated when run from cron or at

Tags: linux, shell, cron

I'm seeing some very strange behavior on a Linux based NAS (DNS-323) I have. I'm using a simple shell script to back up the files on the NAS to another box. After making some recent additions, the script started failing when it ran from `cron` or `at`. It had no issues when I ran the script directly.

After a **lot** of debugging, I finally realized that anything after a certain point simply wasn't executed. It's like the script is cut off. I was able to work around the problem by shortening the script (mostly by removing comments), and now it seems to be working. Although, I'm still curious as to why this is happening.

Has anyone else seen something like this? What could be the cause of this?

Comment: Can you post the script to pastebin or similar?

Comment: Sure thing: http://pastebin.com/x4uDbBFq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The biggest difference here would be that we appear to be working on an embedded system of sorts.

If I'm reading this correctly, it is the script that would appear to be truncated, and not the output (which could then get mailed). I'll cater to each.

If it is in fact the script, but it works when run directly, then I would suggest the following:

1. Is the script particularly large?
2. Does the script feature any Bash-specific features ("bashisms")... note that /bin/sh can -- and often is -- different. You may like to set SHELL=/bin/bash in your crontab (if that's available)
3. Are you trying to write your script in your crontab, or are you calling out to a script file.
4. Does behaviour change if you you redirect *both* stdout and stderr to a file on a filesystem with ample free space?
5. In cases like this, I find it useful to create a temporary crontab entry which calls out to the 'env' command, and redirects it output to a file or email. This can sometimes show unexpected differences in the environment (such as locale settings, which are often different).
6. You can put a 'set -x' in your script file. This will cause it to output debugging information as the script proceeds. You can use 'set +x' to turn it off. This is useful in determining where the script will end executing.
7. What kind of software is being used here:

   - SMTP:  what is the output of 'sendmail --version' or 'sendmail -v'

If in fact it was the output, then I should say the behaviour would depend very much on the MTA being used. In an embedded environment it might exceed a certain buffer size (perhaps this would be driven by available space on the filesystem).

Also, have you checked for updated firmware: http://support.dlink.com/ProductInfo.aspx?m=DNS-323 The latest appears to be version 1.10 from May 2012

Comment: Thanks for all the info. To answer your question, yes, it is the script (not output) that is being truncated. I'm running firmware 1.08 because I've read about some bugs (not sure where) with some of the later firmwares. I'll try some of your debugging suggestions are report back. Also, nothing is being mailed, so SMTP settings should be irrelevant.

Comment: Just to answer a couple more questions. 1) The script is pretty short (roughly 3260 chars). 2) It doesn't use any "bashisms" that I'm aware of. 3) I'm just referencing the script in the crontab. 4) I had the script setup to redirect output on a line by line basis, I'll change that and see if I can redirect stdout and stderr for the entire script.

Comment: Well, I've been trying to reproduce this for the past hour and I can't get it to truncate the script like it did before. I'm running the exact same script, the exact same way with different results now. In light of this, I can't really debug it. If I find some more info, I'll update the question, but for now I'm marking this accepted and moving on. Thanks for the help.